# I can't get the code working to execute a stored procedure using @Ajax.ActionLink MVC EF

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I built that refreshes a lookup table. No rows are returned. It just runs.

**Here is my Ajax link on a View to fire it:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Refresh Sample Points",
        " MakeNewSPIDTable",
        "Home",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "success" 
    }
   )
```

**Here is is Json Action Result in my HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MakeNewSPIDTable()
{

    var bitBucket = _db.ExecuteFunction("sp_RefreshWSFSPIDs");

    return Json("sp ran", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
 }
```

**(The "sp ran" text I hardcoded just to send something back.)**

**Here is the success function that should pop up an Alert:**

```
function success(responseObject) {
    alert(responseObject);
}
```

**I can get the stored procedure to run in all sorts of ways but not with Ajax. I doubt I even have the Ajaz/Jason syntax correct.**

Comment: Have you included unobtrusive ajax in your layouts `<head>`? `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></srcript>`

Comment: The ajax link syntax is correct but I don't understand so did the controller is being call when you select the link?

Comment: Yes it's in the bundle.

Comment: Moy,
Controller gets called, I can put a breakpoint in it. Stored procedure runs because I deleted the table it makes using SQL Server and it made the table. But it doesn't return anything to success function on view.
var bitBucket is -1 in the Immediate window. Which suggests failure, but the table gets re-created which is just what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Alex, Moy, and StackOverflow. And now I have new tool (to me) for troubleshooting this mad scientist stuff. It is Firebug in Mozilla and it shows exactly where a Javascript error happens. Funny, IE4 or so used to just have the error in the bottom frame of the window oh well.

This seems to work and returns alerts for success or failure. I changed a letter in the stored procedure name and it "failed" and popped up the alert. The OnSuccess and OnFailure worked in other words. All they had was an alert in them.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Refresh Sample Points",
        "MakeNewSPIDTable",
        "Home",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "handleResultResponseRefreshSamplePoints()",
        OnFailure = "handleFailedSPIDrefresh()"
}
   )
```

I can live with that because it does what I need. However, I couldn't get the Controller to return a string for success, or I don't have any syntax knowledge of the Json return object. But I hope my simple solution helps someone else.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MakeNewSPIDTable()
{

    var bitBucket = _db.ExecuteFunction("sp_RefreshWSFSPIDs");
    var name = "Json ran stored procedure";
    return Json(name, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
 }
```